# Hy equivalent to * operator in Python's function arguments that forces keyword arguments

Tags: hy

Recently I have been trying to write a simple bot in Hy with Discord.py. In Discord.py we can write a command like this to turn the last argument into a full string that includes spaces:

```py
@commands.command(description="", help="")
async def say(self, ctx, level, *, remains):
    ...
```

But if I write this in Hy as:

```
#@((commands.command :description "" :help "")
        (defn/a say [self ctx level * remains]
            ...))
```

It will complain about missing required argument "text." What's even weirder is that the sample code in the `defn` part on Hy's official website:

```
(defn compare [a b * keyfn [reverse False]]
  (setv result (keyfn a b))
  (if (not reverse)
    result
    (- result)))
```

doesn't even work under `hy --spy`. Did I use it wrong or there's a correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(defn compare…)` works for me. Sounds like the version of Hy you're running doesn't match the version of the documentation you're reading.